# Sequelize: What happens if you insert a record with fields that are not in the database

Tags: sequelize.js

What happens if you attempt to insert a record, using fields that are not in the database model?

For instance:

```
const User = db.define('user', {
  firstName: Sequelize.STRING,
  lastName: Sequelize.STRING
});
User.sync();

let firstUser = User.build(
  firstName: 'Foo',
  lastName: 'Bar',
  baz: 'qux' // not a defined field
);

firstUser.save();
```

What happens?

- Is `baz` ignored?
- Does this throw an error?
- Is there any kind of logging that suggests an additional field was attempted?

Answer (score 0):

### What I've found:

1. Sequelize ignores the additional field(s).
2. All fields that belong to the model are saved.
3. No special logging occurs.  The associated *INSERT* statement includes the recognized (in this case `firstName` and `lastName`) and default fields.